# Opening my "Google Maps Engine" (not google maps) in native app on mobile devices

Tags: android, google-maps, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-engine

I have created a public map using Google Maps Engine. The URL format is https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I would like to create a link to it that will open using the *native* Google Maps app on the user's mobile device.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried the examples here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html using ?mid=xxxx and also comgooglemaps://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx - 

Using the URL schemas explained in that article,I am able to open a GENERIC address using the native app, just not my CUSTOM Google Maps Engine map. Thank you!